# How to call cell value within concatenate function in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have prepared a sheet [pic attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2GVZ.jpg,)

In cell B1, enter a formula

```
>0
```

In the cell CF2, entered a formula

```
=IFS(B1<>"", " AND Col21  "&B1&" " , B1 = "", "")
```

and the result is  AND Col21 >0

In cell CD2, I have entered the formula

```
=IFS(CONCATENATE( CA2, "1")<>"", " AND "&CC2&"  "&CONCATENATE( CA2, "1")&" " , CONCATENATE( CA2, "1") = "", "")
```

and the output is    AND Col21 B1

But, I want to be desired output as   AND Col21 >0

In other words, I need to call the value of the cell B1 instead of the Name B1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try n' wrap the CONCATENATE part of the formula within [INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)*

```js
=let(cell_,indirect(CA2&"1"),
     ifs(cell_<>"", " AND "&CC2&"  "&cell_&" " , cell_="",""))
```